# Partitioning $n$ objects into $k$ boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I know that if $n$ is a positive integer and $n_1,n_2,...n_k$ are positive integers such that $n=n_1+n_2+...+n_k$. Then the number of ways to partition $n$ objects into k boxes is:

If $n_1=n_2=....=n_k$ and the boxes are unlabeled, then it is equal to $\frac{n!}{n_1!\cdot n_2!\cdot...\cdot n_k!}$

But what if $n_j$'s are not necessarily the same? I could not find a formula for that. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Exactly the formula you give, it doesn't depend on the $n_i$s being the same.

Comment: If the boxes are unlabeled, what (if anything) do the summands $n_i$ have to do with the boxes?  Also you need to specify whether the objects are distinguishable (assuming the boxes are not distinguishable in your problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m assuming that the $n$ objects are distinguishable and that $n_1,\dots,n_k$ are the specified sizes of the pieces of the partition. The number of such partitions is

$$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\dots n_k!}$$

regardless of whether the $n_i$’s are the same or different. This number is a [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), a generalization of the more familiar binomial coefficient; it can be written

$$\binom{n}{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k}=\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\dots n_k!}\;.$$

**Added 13 April 2020:**

As a couple of commenters have noted, the original question is a bit confused: **alev** speaks of the boxes being unlabelled but gives a formula that is correct for labelled boxes. My answer was based on the assumption that ‘unlabelled’ was an error and that the formula was consistent with **alev**’s actual intent; if the boxes really are supposed to be unlabelled, the problem is of course a bit harder in general.

Suppose that there are $n$ unlabelled boxes, $n_1,\ldots,n_m$ are the **distinct** box sizes, and that for $i=1,\ldots,m$ there are $r_i$ boxes of size $n_i$, so that $\sum_{i=1}^mr_i=k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^mr_in_i=n$. Then the number of partitions is

$$\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^mr_i!(n_i!)^{r_i}}\;,$$

which reduces to the multinomial coefficient only when $m=k$.

Comment: The one thorn is where the OP says "the boxes are unlabeled", which seems more or less to ask for partitions having specified sizes rather than (ordered) selections (mappings to $k$ labelled boxes) with the specified sizes.  However as OP asserts the multinomial gives the right answer for equal summands $n_i$, the natural extension is worth stating (as also @vonbrand commented).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've downvoted this answer (and the question) since it doesn't answer the question as stated by OP, right?, because the multinomial coefficient counts partitions into labelled boxes. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @RobertDodier: Apparently it answered the question that the OP wanted answered, though it’s also possible that the OP was confused on that point. Unfortunately, the OP hasn’t been around in some years, so we’re unlikely to get any clarification at this point. I appreciate your leaving an explanatory comment, but I think that both of your downvotes are unnecessary, if not a bit petty: **hardmath**’s comment seems to clarify the situation adequately, and it’s not unusual for questions to be misstated.  If you like, however, I can incorporate a similar comment in the answer.

Comment: Well, um, don't take it personally. The problem is that the question and answer are confusing to people who end up here from searching for partitioning-into-boxes problems. It takes careful reading to figure out what the question and what the answer are about, but that seems pointless -- there are other questions and answers which are clearer. The purpose of downvoting, to the extent that it changes anything, is to steer traffic towards other questions.

Comment: @RobertDodier: I don’t think that that reflects actual practice. Questions (other than spam and the like) tend to be downvoted primarily for lack of effort. I also disagree: in my view the only legitimate reasons for downvoting an answer (again apart from spam, etc.) is that it is mathematically incorrect, is unclear even to those who understand the material, or fails to address the question. (E.g., some good answers do not completely answer a question, either because they are hints or because the question really is hard.) It’s the upvotes that should help to steer traffic for those who ...

Comment: @RobertDodier: ... actually pay attention to the numbers. (I don’t, having found them generally rather useless.) In any case my first concern is always for the person who asked the question.