# Dividing N Distinct Objects into K groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How to divide N distinct objects in a group of 2(or group of k) such that each group should contain at least 1 object.
I found a similar post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314492/partitioning-n-objects-into-k-boxes). But that does not answer my question neither i am able to understand. can someone help?

Comment: Are the objects identical?  If so you are just looking to count the number of $k-$tuples of positive numbers that sum to $N$, and the answer is given by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: No, as per the question they are not identical.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates that.  The question makes sense either way, so the ambiguity should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In case of 2 groups, the first object(denoted as A) of $n $ objects can go any group, and the rest can go either the group that A belongs or the other. So there are in total $2^{n-1}-1 $ ways because the case where every object belongs to one single group should be taken out. For k groups, the number of ways is $S (n,~k) $, where $S $ denotes the stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: Suppose we have 2 distinct objects(say A and B). Then object A goes into Group1 and ObjectB goes into Group2.  Then ObjectA goes into Group2 and ObjectB into Group1.  so there are two ways of grouping an object. But your formula gives only 1 group. could you please explain

Comment: Are the groups distinct? Then multiply 2.